# Does windows Azure powershell commandlets have built-in transient fault handling & retry logic in-built?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am planning to use [Windows Azure PowerShell commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495240.aspx) for working with Blob Storage.  My question is whether commands like "Get-AzureStorageBlobContent" have built in transient fault handling and retry logic built-in similar to [AZCopy.exe](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/09/07/azcopy-transfer-data-with-re-startable-mode-and-sas-token.aspx). In fact, for my use case of moving files between on-premise and Azure, I am evaluating between azcopy.exe and azure PowerShell commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the PowerShell Cmdlets do have built-in retry logics. Similar with AzCopy; it will retry for requests against the storage service. AzCopy is designed for a set of files transfer, so it has some additional retry logic. For example, if you break AzCopy in middle (with a journal file enabled by /z), it will retry the failed cases before.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which cmdlets.  The bulk of them do have standard retry logic.